# sending multiform data with DUPLICATE KEYS in nodejs

Tags: node.js, forms, http, request

I need to send a POST request with NodeJS to an API that requires the same multiform key be used more than once.

This is a CURL example of the required action:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer MY_ACCESS_TOKEN" -i -X POST -F "whitespace=1" \
    -F "terms[]=lait" -F "definitions[]=milk" -F "terms[]=petits pois" \
    -F "definitions[]=peas" -F "title=My first set via the API" \
    -F "lang_terms=fr" -F "lang_definitions=en" \
    https://api.quizlet.com/2.0/sets
```

As you can see, the keys "terms[]" and "definitions[]" are used more than once in the same request.

I've tried using the nodejs request/http/multi-form libraries with no success, as most of them require a JavaScript object to define the form data, which of course cannot accept duplicate keys.

Other than resorting to an exec() command to cURL, is there any nodejs library that will enable me to send a request with duplicate multiform keys?

I'm really banging my head against a wall with this one..

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. Why send duplicate keys when you could.. not?

Comment: The duplicate keys are required by the API, which unfortunately I have no control over.. :-/

Comment: Its look like u r trying to send array values in a key, u can send multiple values in a single array key, no need to duplicate.

Comment: First check your API with some rest clients like postman or advanced rest client

Comment: @MohammadRaheem The API will not accept an array of values (I've tried this) – it only accepts a single value per key

Comment: @iambatman I've tested it with Postman, and it works, but the NodeJS code that Postman generates does not work - it either overwrites the duplicate keys or just misses them out

Answer (score 0):

Try this its an example with `request` library

```
let options = { method: 'POST',
            url:url,
            headers: 
            {
                'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                 authorization: 'Bearer '+accessToken ,
                'content-type': 'application/json' 
            },
            body: 
            { //your array here
              terms:['terms'] ,
              definitions:['milk'] 
            },
            json: true 
            };

            request(options, function (error, response, body) {

                    if(error){
                       console.log("Error ",error);
                     }                          

                      console.log("Response",body);
               })
```

Answer (score 0):

With unirest:

```
var unirest = require('unirest');
var req = unirest('POST', 'YOUR URL')
  .headers({
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------846713359653092950719061',
    'Authorization': 'YOUR AUTH'
  })
  .field('AAA', 'VAL1')
  .field('AAA', 'VAL2')
  .field('AAA', 'VAL3')
  .end(function (res) { 
    if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error); 
    console.log(res.raw_body);
  });
```